# Simple apache proxy not working

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, application-server

I just wanted to test a reverse proxy simple setup, redirecting every request just to google. Anyhow it does not work! Trying to browse on localhost, I just get the apache "it works" default page, but not proxying.

Of course I loaded the modules proxy, proxy_http. Following file is placed under sites-available, with symbolic link in sites-enabled. I also restarted the server. What could be wrong?

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:8080>
      ProxyRequests off
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      <proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      </proxy >
      ProxyPass / http://www.google.de
      ProxyPassReverse / http://www.google.de
</VirtualHost >
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default vhost (which serves content from `/var/www`, where the "It works" page lives) is getting the requests.

It's loading first, and you haven't specified a `ServerName` for your new vhost, so the "default" vhost will get every request.  Run `apache2ctl -S` - it will show you how it's assigning requests.

If you don't want to use the default site, disable it with `a2dissite default`, then restart Apache - requests will then be sent to your new proxying `<VirtualHost>`.

Additionally, your trailing slashes should always match when proxying.  Add them at the end:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.google.de/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.google.de/
```

Comment: I'm testing out the above but when I run apachectl -S I don't see my port being forwarded.  I only see port 443 and port 80.  Any ideas?  @Shane Madden

Comment: Ugh never mind I was editing the wrong file @Shane Madden

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is facing this, note that just reloading apache is not enough.

I had to restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Did you enable a module in the process? A reload usually suffices for config changes, a restart is only needed for module changes.