# How to make ProxyPass change URLs?

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm a currently trying to use ProxyPass to change a request to my server into a request to a different API server. However, all of the requests seem to be going to the Apache start page and not being changed at all.

I had been using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) guide in order to try and set up the server, which is where I got the below conf file from.

Here is my current 000-default.conf file in the sites-enabled directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "https://api.net/example/:80"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://api.net/example/:80"
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ServerName http://52.89.79.213/
</VirtualHost>
```

I was reading [this](https://serverfault.com/a/413425/376791) answer and tried to follow the given answer by changing the ServerName in my new VirtualHost to the IP address of my server, and I also tried running the command a2dissite default, but I get the message "Site default does not exist!".

What could be the problem with my configuration? Should I remove the first VirtualHost brackets, as they are just for the Apache start page? When I do this, I get an internal server error. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your request hits `<VirtualHost *:80>` which is not configured for `ProxyPass`. Also `https://api.net/example/:80` is a bad notation, `https://api.net/example:80` is a right notation. But wait...`https` against port 80 ??...Clean up your config!

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Sorry, I am completely new to Apache. I just got it to work!